# Use CSS and JavaScript in Java desktop application program

Tags: java, javascript, html, swing, css

Can I use CSS or other web technologies in a Java desktop application by any means?

Note: I know as I used they are web based resources, but I want to know the ways it can be used in a Java desktop application.

Comment: why do you want to use?? if you want that kind of functionality..Directly use JavaFX..don;t need to use javascript

Comment: For Windows only there's this... http://www.genuitec.com/about/labs-webkit-for-swt/WebKit%20For%20SWT%20Developer%20Guide.html

Comment: http://fxexperience.com/ try this out

Comment: `JEditorPane` supports simple CSS (& a sub-set of HTML 3.2), but not JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS in your Java desktop application, but you can't use JavaScript. Here is the links, you can learn how to use CSS in a Swing application'.

1. http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2003/10/14/swingcss.html
2. http://tutiez.com/how-to-use-css-style-or-stylesheet-in-java-swing-jeditorpane.html

Personally, I recommended to use the 'Look And Feel' features in your application.

Comment: But you CAN use JavaScript in a Java desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in another answer, you can use CSS. You can also use JavaScript using Java's `ScriptEngine` class.

Here is the documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/